# TypeError: this is undefined inside an ajax call and google app maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have an asp mvc project where the user is asked for geolocalization via google maps (API), so i had to use jquery 1.7.2 and save it's coordinates, but when i try to save them via ajax request i get this error on firebug and stops all the other code.

http://i47.photobucket.com/albums/f195/warbandit69/ErrorKambi1_zpsac3979f4.png

As you can see the error is very unacurte with it's description, and here is the function on jquery that makes that call

```
function ReviewAtEnd() {
        if (typeof (idserialF) != "undefined" && idserialF != null) {
            var datax = { idjob: idjobx, latitud: Latitud, longitud: Longitud, coordinates: coordenadasGM };
            var urlx = "/JOBS/PROG41/FailedItemOnSite";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlx,
                data: datax,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    mostrar_alert_ui(data.titulo, data.mensaje, 350);
                    if (data.success) {
                        AfterPassedTest();
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("Failed " + urlx);
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the google maps function i missed to show you

```
var Latitud;
    var Longitud;
    var coordenadasGM;
    function showMap() {

        //If HTML5 Geolocation Is Supported In This Browser
        if (navigator.geolocation) {

            //Use HTML5 Geolocation API To Get Current Position
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

                //Get Latitude From Geolocation API
                var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                Latitud = latitude;

                //Get Longitude From Geolocation API
                var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                Longitud = Longitud;

                //Define New Google Map With Lat / Lon
                var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                coordenadasGM = coords;

                //Specify Google Map Options
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: coords,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL }, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: coords,
                    map: map,
                    title: "You Are Here!"
                });

            }
            );

        } else {

            //Otherwise - Gracefully Fall Back If Not Supported... Probably Best Not To Use A JS Alert Though :)
            mostrar_alert_ui("WARNING", "Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.", 350)
        }

    }

    //Once Page Is Populated - Initiate jQuery
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Show The Map
        showMap();

        // When The Viewing Window Is Resized
        $(window).resize(function () {

            //CSS Resizes Container So Lets Recall The Map Function
            showMap();

        });

    });
```

Jsfiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/ricardojriosr/9mzss1ud/

Comment: The error obviously comes from the maps-API(the part that triggers the error looks like the toString-method of LatLng), but none of your code is related to the maps-API, impossible to give an answer based on the given code.

Comment: However, this error makes no sense. Try to run it in e.g. chrome, maybe you get another error(There are often incorrect error-reports in firebug, especially when jquery is loaded)

Comment: @Dr.Molle just updated the question with GM function

Comment: @Dr.Molle Chrome error -> http://i47.photobucket.com/albums/f195/warbandit69/ErrorChrome_zps19f16402.png